# Select grouping by and sum a column with the same amount

Tags: mysql

So, I have a table called 'sales' in my MySQL Database.

This table has the following columns: id, product_id (which is a foreign key for products table), amount (how many of this product were sold), and others, but those are the important ones.

**So, I'd like to select for each product how many products were sold.**

If I do:

```
SELECT * FROM sales GROUP BY product_id
```

Then the sales with the same product_id but different amount will merge in a single row. Actually, I would like to sum the amount of the products with the same product_id but different amount..

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to group by product_id and by amount and sum the data, like this:

```
SELECT product_id, amount, SUM(amount) AS amount_sum
    FROM sales
    GROUP BY product_id, amount
```

Comment: Thank you, it gave me a north for my answer.